# Object of class [org.jongo.bson.RelaxedLazyDBObject] must be an instance of class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

Tags: spring, mongodb, testing

I'm trying to setup tests with Spring Boot and Mongo Embedded (JHipster, Flapdoodle).
In general it works. I can see database in Robomongo with created test collections and objects (migrations using Mongobee).

But when I want to access Clients collection:

```
    List clients = clientRepository.findAll();
```

It throws:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given DBObject must be a BasicDBObject! Object of class [org.jongo.bson.RelaxedLazyDBObject] must be an instance of class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
```

When I run application with real Mongo instance:
./mvnw -Pdev
there are no errors even though test and dev configurations use the same Mongobee mibrations.

Spring documentation is very laconic:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongo-embedded

My test configuration file application.yml is:

```
    spring:
        mongodb:
            embedded:
                version: 3.2.1
        data:
            mongodb:
                host: localhost
                port: 27117
                database: mydb-test
```

I use Mongo (real instance) version v3.2.7, in configuration highest possible version of Embedded Mongo which I set is 3.2.1, maybe this could be a problem?
Maybe someone could share his configuration with example working tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find my self the solution.

Problem was that I used **org.jongo.Jongo** instead of JHipster default **com.mongodb.Db** in @ChangeSet.

For some reasons Jongo doesn't work well with Embedded Mongo.
When I switched to Db, all problems has gone.

NOT WORKING:

```
@ChangeSet(...)
public void someChange(Jongo jongo) throws IOException {

    org.jongo.MongoCollection collection = jongo.getCollection("collection");
    DBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
    collection.insert(basicDBObject);

     ...
}
```

WORKING:

```
@ChangeSet(...)
public void someChange(Db db) throws IOException {

    com.mongodb.MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
    DBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
    collection.insert(basicDBObject);
    ...
}
```